# Active and full OpenCL/GL bindings for C#/Mono

Tags: c#, opengl, mono, opencl

I have seen OpenTK, but the last release was more than year ago. Any other offers?

Can somebody also suggest mathematics libraries for C#/Mono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono is currently planning a pretty large 1.1 update, it's not dead. If you absolutely need something like OpenGL 4.2 bindings, you can download the OpenTK source code and use it's generator to download the OpenGL 4.2 spec files and create the new bindings, then compile OpenTK for your own use. If you extend the GameWindow class, you've already got cross-platform context and window creation, it's pretty nice.

OpenTK has a pretty solid math library too, and methods like `glUniformMatrix4fv()` have overloads for `OpenTK.Matrix4`.

1 year doesn't really make a project inactive, considering your only other option is Tao, which last released an update in 2005 and has hardcoded bindings only up to OpenGL 2.1